# Exibir botão de Rota Google Maps automaticamente

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

Tenho o seguinte método pra criação do Marker no App:

```
private void createMarker()
{
    MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mObjetoResumo.getLatitude(), mObjetoResumo.getLongitude());
    mo.position(latLng);
    mo.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
    final Marker m = mMap.addMarker(mo);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, Constants.MAX_ZOOM));
    m.showInfoWindow();

}
```

Como chamo o `showInfoWindow` as informações do Pin são exibidas sem problemas, minha dúvida e como faço para que o botão de rotas seja exibido automaticamente?

[image: map]

Este, aparece apenas após o usuário clicar sobre o `Marker`.

Gostaria de saber como exibir estes botões sem a necessidade de mais um click por parte do usuário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma.

Removi a opção default do mapa :

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

E implementei dois botões para realizar a ações:

```
ImageView routeButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.routeButton);
    routeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final String url = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%s,%s",  mObjetoResumo.getLatitude().toString(), mObjetoResumo.getLongitude().toString() );
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


ImageView gMapButton =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gMapButton);
       gMapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                final String url = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "http://maps.google.com/maps?z=%s&q=loc:%s+%s", (Constants.MAX_ZOOM+""),  mObjetoResumo.getLatitude().toString(), mObjetoResumo.getLongitude().toString() );
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```